# Perform Chi-Square independence test with log-transformed percentage data?

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, data-transformation, logarithm

I am in the woods now with the appropriate way to analyze my data. Some parameters:

1. The format of the raw outcome variable is percentage (attendance rate).
2. It is left-skewed initially. So I tried log and square transformation, while log10 transformation turned it to approximate normal distribution.
3. My goal = to detect any significant difference in the log-transformed outcome variable between two independent groups (IV is a binary variable)

**Question** =
Should I use an independent t-test or Chi-square test (given it is originally in percentage after all)

P.S.
by eyeballing the results, the t-test gives no sig, while Chi-Square gives significant results at .0001...
**Thank you so much for your time and support!**

Comment: The chi squared test doesn't make sense here - what is your expected attendance rate under the chi squared test's null hypothesis? Chi squared is used when you have a set of percentages that must total to 100%, not when you have percentages in general. For example, exam scores can be expressed as percentages, but you'd want to use a t test if you were comparing scores between two groups of students.

Comment: Thank you so much, @rishi-k! I concur with you that the nature of the data may not fit well with the Chi-square. Some follow-up questions if you or our friends have time :), (1) you mentioned that "...that must total to 100%". Could you offer some references that elaborate on this argument? (2) the samples are unbalanced, so I prefer not to use t-test even with adjustment. I binned the log-transformed percentage into a categorical variable. Will this allow me to perform the Chi-square test? I hesitate because the interpretability will be messy, but that is less of a concern for this project.

Comment: Chi squared is specifically meant to deal with contingency tables, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table. How unbalanced are your samples? And how many samples are there? Welch's approximation to the t-test is quite robust to unbalanced samples.

Comment: The chi-squared test of independence is for a contingency table whose elements are *counts*; the variance is wrong otherwise. If you want to use it on percentages, you have to modify it for sample size (at which point it becomes algebraically identical to calculating it on the counts). You cannot just use arbitrary quantities like transformed percentages in place of counts, and you cannot use it on things that aren't contingency tables.

Comment: Could you show us a plot of your data? Sample size? Or even share (a link to) the data? But the answer is already practically answered in comments, chi-squared tet is irrelevant here

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your kind support and informative comments! I think I have a good idea and solution thanks to you all! I love this community!